# How to execute each line separately

Tags: bash

I have for example a text with

```
2 3
4 5
```

and when I want to grep the first word in

```
$firstword
```

I get

```
2
4
```

and it is the same with the second word.
and when I do

```
echo $firstword $secondword
```

I get: 2 3 4 5

So my question is
how can I still have

```
2 3
4 5
```

when i put them in a variabele and then use echo.
Thank you

Comment: How do you `grep` that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have `$'2\n4'` in a variable, there's no way how you can print it followed by something and get `2 3 4 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` by itself is not capable. `paste` works here

```bash
paste -d ' ' <(echo "$firstword") <(echo "$secondword")
```

The [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)s
make paste read from `echo "$firstword"` and `echo "$secondword"` as if they were files. Take note, the quotes are **required**.